# Смена изображений на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Хочу менять изображение при клике.

```
var view = 5;
var url = '/images/'+view+'.jpg?'+random;
$('#popup').find('img').attr('src', url);
```

Проблема в том, что url картинки подменяется сразу, а браузер обновляет картинку только через несколько секунд. 
Как сделать так, чтобы изображение сразу по клику. Возможно вставить как-то loader, и ждать загрузки изображения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

Во-первых, надо сделать предзагрузку спиннера, чтобы не мерцал

```
(new Image()).src = '/path/to/spinner.gif';
```

Во-вторых, задать класс для изображений загружающихся со спиннером

```
img.loading {
    background: transparent url(/path/to/spinner.gif) no-repeat scroll center center;
}
```

Наконец установить его для нужных изображений

```
<img src="/path/to/real/image.jpg" class="loading">
```

Когда изображение загрузится, оно просто перекроет фон со спиннером.

Comment: нет, не известно

Comment: Исправил ответ.

Comment: Новая проблема. Если src картинки меняется, то в коде она меняется быстро, а браузер не успевает.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по коду, у вас неизвестны картинки, которые вы грузите, если бы они были известны, то лучше использовать спрайты, ими Вы убьете двух зайцев - не будет времени ожидания загрузки, а также уменьшите нагрузку траффика.

Предлагаю Вам при клике загрузить картинку, после полной загрузки отображать popup. Например:

```
$('#popup').on('click', function(){
  $.get('url', function(){
    //load image
  }).done(function(){
    //show popup
  });
});
```